# Checking wether a directory exist in the home directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Trying to check wether a directory exist in the the home directory

```
if [  ! -d "$HOME/Smart_Cycle"  ]; then
    mkdir Smart_Cycle $DIRPATH
    echo "Creating DIrecroty""
fi
```

Trying to check wether the Smart_Cycle directory exist in the home directory, and if it does not exist it will create the directory. Not sure what is going on or if I am on the right track.

When running the script I have these two error that I have never seen before

./smartcycle: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./smartcycle: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Is this not working? Do you care if the directory doesn't exist and you needed to create it? Because if you don't then just `mkdir -p "$HOME/Smart_Cycle"` is probably what you want. Add `-v` if you want a message about it.

Comment: What does the -p option do in the command, and would you put the v option after the -p option?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir and any of `mkdir -v -p`, `mkdir -vp`, `mkdir -p -v` or `mkdir -pv` would use both options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an extra quotation mark on

```
echo "Creating DIrecroty""
```

Try this

```
if [  ! -d "$HOME/Smart_Cycle"  ]; then
  mkdir "$HOME/Smart_Cycle"
  echo "Creating DIrecroty"
fi
```

You can create more than one directory at once

```
mkdir A B C
```

In your case, $DIRPATH will be evaluated and a second directory created pointing to the value contained in $DIRPATH

Comment: The whole point of `mkdir -p` is that the conditional is unnecessary.  If the directory already existed, nothing happens; if not, it is created.

Comment: true, let also note that `mkdir -p` will make parent directories as needed.

Answer (score 1):

EOF is because you have double "" in

```
"Creating DIrecroty""
```

As Etan suggested, a better way is to use

```
mkdir -p "$HOME/Smart_Cycle"
```

-p will make sure that all directories in the specified path exist and if not, they will be created.

Comment: I am not sure that `-p` is needed *here* : `$HOME` should be an existing directory, and `Smart_Cycle` is only one directory deep

Comment: without -p, mkdir "$HOME/Smart_Cycle" will fail if 'Smart_Cycle' directory exists

Comment: Is there a website that list possible errors and an explanation about them?